# Create logical list with strsplit on combined words to subset data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split, split-apply-combine

I have tried to subset my data frame according a condition on specific column. For this purpose I need to create TRUE or FALSE info for each line on this column. But some line on this column has combine words and my code can not detect them.

```
p <- sapply(strsplit(test$hashtags, split=","), function(x)any(x%in%"evet"))
```

When you check the sample data you can easily see that line 5,7,8 have specific word but they are showed as a FALSE.

I have tried to add "unlist" command in my code but it haven't worked for me.

```
p <- sapply(unlist(strsplit(test$hashtags, split=",")), function(x)any(x%in%"evet"))
```

I need to create one FALSE or TRUE condition according specific word for combined line even though there are more than one words. 
Thanks for in advance.

Sample Data:

```
test <- structure(list(created_at = structure(c(1489636860, 1489636860, 
1489636860, 1489636860, 1489636860, 1489636860, 1489636860, 1489636860, 
1489636860, 1489636860), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    user.screen_name = c("bilge_bilir", "memetozturk93", "Byomeraslan", 
    "tmremolar", "orhanyilmaz_77", "tamdere", "EriVatan", "BaySancaktar", 
    "zeynepmekik", "EriVatan"), entities.hashtags = list(structure(list(
        indices = list(c(84L, 90L)), text = "Hayır"), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        indices = list(c(65L, 70L)), text = "evet"), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        indices = list(c(98L, 103L)), text = "Evet"), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        indices = list(c(98L, 104L)), text = "Hayır"), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        indices = list(c(28L, 33L), c(45L, 50L), c(89L, 94L)), 
        text = c("EVET", "EVET", "EVET")), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), structure(list(
        indices = list(c(38L, 43L)), text = "EVET"), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        indices = list(c(20L, 29L), c(36L, 46L), c(89L, 94L)), 
        text = c("Dirilişe", "Yükselişe", "Evet")), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), structure(list(
        indices = list(c(10L, 15L), c(16L, 20L), c(21L, 26L), 
            c(27L, 31L)), text = c("Evet", "Eri", "Beli", "Yes"
        )), .Names = c("indices", "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    4L)), structure(list(indices = list(c(125L, 130L)), text = "Evet"), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        indices = list(c(102L, 107L)), text = "EVET"), .Names = c("indices", 
    "text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), retweeted_status.created_at = c("Thu Mar 16 03:49:15 +0000 2017", 
    "Wed Mar 15 23:57:44 +0000 2017", "Wed Mar 15 21:07:54 +0000 2017", 
    "Wed Mar 15 20:54:43 +0000 2017", "Wed Mar 15 14:41:15 +0000 2017", 
    "Wed Mar 15 23:07:43 +0000 2017", "Wed Mar 15 15:41:06 +0000 2017", 
    NA, "Wed Mar 15 11:13:15 +0000 2017", "Wed Mar 15 16:37:13 +0000 2017"
    ), entities.user_mentions = list(structure(list(indices = list(
        c(3L, 16L), c(18L, 30L), c(44L, 55L), c(56L, 71L), c(72L, 
        83L)), screen_name = c("seremgiz8289", "bilge_bilir", 
    "OduncuTimi", "yalcinvelioglu", "OPTlMlst_Z"), id = c(301944248, 
    2189106581, 2756465282, 2668851081, 2734161237), id_str = c("301944248", 
    "2189106581", "2756465282", "2668851081", "2734161237"), 
        name = c("ATA KIZI HAYIR DİYOR", "Bilge Eryuz", "OduncuTimi ®", 
        "Yalçın Velioğlu", "OPTlMlst_Z")), .Names = c("indices", 
    "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    5L)), structure(list(indices = list(c(3L, 16L)), screen_name = "kendimce_ben", 
        id = 2322523731, id_str = "2322523731", name = "İzzet#EVET/\U0001f1f9\U0001f1f7"), .Names = c("indices", 
    "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(indices = list(c(3L, 12L)), screen_name = "omrolcay", 
            id = 360420809L, id_str = "360420809", name = "Ömer Olcay"), .Names = c("indices", 
        "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(indices = list(c(3L, 18L)), screen_name = "mehmet_asassoy", 
            id = 3151503430, id_str = "3151503430", name = "Mehmet Asassoy"), .Names = c("indices", 
        "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(indices = list(c(3L, 17L), c(120L, 132L
        )), screen_name = c("sevincbeykent", "yigitbulutt"), 
            id = c(538364458L, 256065299L), id_str = c("538364458", 
            "256065299"), name = c("Sevinç", "YİĞİT BULUT"
            )), .Names = c("indices", "screen_name", "id", "id_str", 
        "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), structure(list(
            indices = list(c(3L, 13L)), screen_name = "AKsamet54", 
            id = 313205928L, id_str = "313205928", name = "Samet ÇELİK"), .Names = c("indices", 
        "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(indices = list(c(3L, 18L)), screen_name = "HayataTebessum", 
            id = 2911157237, id_str = "2911157237", name = "Meryem"), .Names = c("indices", 
        "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(indices = list(c(0L, 9L)), screen_name = "4qet1dil", 
            id = 536676261L, id_str = "536676261", name = "KerenGo"), .Names = c("indices", 
        "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(indices = list(c(3L, 18L)), screen_name = "akkadinantalya", 
            id = 1898504755L, id_str = "1898504755", name = "AK Kadın Antalya"), .Names = c("indices", 
        "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(indices = list(c(3L, 15L)), screen_name = "menes__2010", 
            id = 186968367L, id_str = "186968367", name = "#EVET☪ ياسين ☝"), .Names = c("indices", 
        "screen_name", "id", "id_str", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    hashtags = c("hayir", "evet", "evet", "hayir", "c(\"evet\", \"evet\", \"evet\")", 
    "evet", "c(\"dirilise\", \"yukselise\", \"evet\")", "c(\"evet\", \"eri\", \"beli\", \"yes\")", 
    "evet", "evet"), mentions = list(c("seremgiz8289", "bilge_bilir", 
    "OduncuTimi", "yalcinvelioglu", "OPTlMlst_Z"), "kendimce_ben", 
        "omrolcay", "mehmet_asassoy", c("sevincbeykent", "yigitbulutt"
        ), "AKsamet54", "HayataTebessum", "4qet1dil", "akkadinantalya", 
        "menes__2010")), .Names = c("created_at", "user.screen_name", 
"entities.hashtags", "retweeted_status.created_at", "entities.user_mentions", 
"hashtags", "mentions"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is mostly because the way `hashtags` column was generated. It was stored as a list of character vector and when coerced to character it gave this structure.

See for example,

```
list(c("A", "B", "C"))
#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" 

as.character(list(c("A", "B", "C"))) 
#[1] "c(\"A\", \"B\", \"C\")"
```

Checking an individual element on your dataframe gives the same structure.

```
test$hashtags[5]
#[1] "c(\"evet\", \"evet\", \"evet\")"
```

So if there is no way you could go back and change the way `hashtags` columns was generated you can use `grepl` instead and it would save you from `strsplit` and `sapply` call as well.

```
grepl("evet", test$hashtags)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak Shah. It works for only one word but I have a few words list object so how can I improve it for list object. My function like this find_sides <- function(side_hashtag, side_list){
  sapply(strsplit(side_hashtag, split=","), function(x)any(x%in%side_list))
} .....   I have changed into this but it did't work. find_sides <- function(side_hashtag, side_list){
  sapply(strsplit(side_hashtag, split=","), function(x)any(grepl(sidelist, x)))
} . Thanks

Comment: @eabanoz but that updated function does work for your sample data , right?

Comment: no it didn't work. It gives "Warning messages:
1: In grepl(sidelist, x) : argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". As you can see it only use the first word so it creates same data frame for each word.

Comment: @eabanoz If you have `sidelist` as character vector, can you try `sapply(strsplit(side_hashtag, split=","), function(x)any(grepl(paste0(sidelist, collapse = "|"), x))) ` . In the given example it has only one pattern so, `sapply(strsplit(test$hashtags, split=","), function(x) any(grepl("evet", x)))` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `grepl` here:

```
p <- sapply(strsplit(test$hashtags, split=","), function(x) {
    grepl("evet", x)
})
```

If you really wanted to match the standalone word `evet`, then use word boundaries:

```
p <- sapply(strsplit(test$hashtags, split=","), function(x) {
    grepl("\bevet\b", x)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical index column with `str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- test %>% 
          mutate(ind = str_detect(hashtags, pattern = "evet")) 
out$ind
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If we need to get the logical index for each word

```
test %>% 
   mutate(ind = str_extract_all(hashtags, "\\w+") %>%
                             map(str_detect, pattern = "evet"))
```